# Calculate tree sums per level using LINQ

Tags: angular, linq, d3.js, asp.net-core

I have successfully created a tree with the following data I'm serving from `.net core Web API`. I'm using `angular 4` and `d3.js` to render the tree. Apart from `Id` and `parentId` properties the data-set also has other properties such as `unitPrice`. I want to be able to calculate the totals per level considering that each level has it's own unitPrice e.g as per the tree diagram, **Level 1** would be `100 * 10 = 1000`. I managed to calculate all Level sums with [Underscore Js](http://underscorejs.org/), but I'd like to do all this functionality from the `Web API` side using `Linq. I'd have added what I've done so far, but it's mostly in angular, which is irrelevant to this question. Is there a way to do it with **Linq**?

```
     ## Id ##                           **parentId**
     ecbaee24da9c6ae57bd195bb53a8c157   null
     9b96247538f35dbe04e86200ebb4908b   ecbaee24da9c6ae57bd195bb53a8c157
     15a987d0c84833ca4bfe61c77dae1fc0   9b96247538f35dbe04e86200ebb4908b
     491ee869a19bd81bbe9fb39dc924d238   15a987d0c84833ca4bfe61c77dae1fc0
     da7c474ce0cda9e6591a6e5c7dcefe42   ecbaee24da9c6ae57bd195bb53a8c157
     cf27768cffb96d72b40b2a2801164a40   da7c474ce0cda9e6591a6e5c7dcefe42
```

Here is the tree image.
[image]

Comment: I think you could try to use `GroupBy` to group your elements by `parentId`, then use `Select` to compute price*unitPrice or something

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. That will work for the first level but I doubt for the subsequent levels..

Comment: Can you can add property `public int levelUnitPrice get { return items.Where(x => Id == x.parentId).Sum(x => x.unitPrice); }` to your class, it will be serialized and sent to client.

Comment: I don't understand how your tree diagram relates to your question? Also, totals of what values?

Comment: Each record from the table has a parent, except the first, which is the root node. An example of a node from the table is `ecbaee24da9c6ae57bd195bb53a8c157` and its children are `9b96247538f35dbe04e86200ebb4908b` and `da7c474ce0cda9e6591a6e5c7dcefe42`. I wanted the sums of `unitPrice` for each level.